# Linking Ipopt with Intel MKL

Tags: c++, lapack, blas, intel-mkl, ipopt

I'm trying to link Ipopt with Intel MKL ([instructions](http://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node14.html)).

[Intel's Link Advisor](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor) suggests:

Link line:

```
 -Wl,--start-group ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread -lm -ldl
```

Compiler options:

```
 -DMKL_ILP64 -qopenmp -I${MKLROOT}/include
```

I try to configure Ipopt with:

```
../configure CXX=icpc CC=icc F77=ifort --with-blas=" -Wl,--start-group ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_ilp64.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a ${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.a -Wl,--end-group -lpthread -lm -ldl" CXXFLAGS=" -DMKL_ILP64 -qopenmp -I${MKLROOT}/include"
```

This eventually fails indicating:

```
checking whether user supplied BLASLIB=[text above]  does not work
```

Comment: Which version of MKL are you using?

Comment: I just downloaded Parallel Studio 2016 update 3, so my guess is the latest one, which I think is 11.3.2

Comment: What is the output of the command `echo ${MKLROOT}` on your machine?

Comment: @Eric `./mklvars intel64` does not appear to work.  So $MKLROOT has no value, so for now I assumed it would be `/opt/intel/mkl`

Comment: How do you find `mklvars` ? it should be `source /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2016.2.062/psxevars.sh intel64` in your `.bashrc`

Comment: It's `/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2016.3.210/linux/mkl`

Comment: make sure MKL is correctly configured and then follow the link line advisor.

Comment: @Eric How do I check it's correctly configured?  Btw, I updated the question.

Comment: make sure $MKLROOT is corrcet. and use dynamic MKL with Ipopt. Static one seems not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to make sure that MKL is correctly installed and configured as shown here.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-with-parallel-studio-xe-for-linux

A permanent way is to put the following line in your `.bashrc` or `.profile`

```
source /opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2016.<##>.<###>/psxevars.sh intel64
```

You could use the following cmdline to check if MKL is ready. It should display the valid MKL installation dir.

```
$ echo $MKLROOT
```

---

If you are using MKL link line advisor, why don't you follow the instruction precisely? I noticed you miss the OpenMP lib `-liomp5` in link option, and the whole compile option.

I can build Ipopt with single dynamic MKL by

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../configure --with-blas=' -Wl,--no-as-needed -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64  -lmkl_rt -lpthread -lm -ldl' CFLAGS=' -m64 -I${MKLROOT}/include' CXXFLAGS=' -m64 -I${MKLROOT}/include'
```

and with dynamic MKL by

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../configure --with-blas='-Wl,--no-as-needed -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl' CFLAGS=' -m64 -I${MKLROOT}/include' CXXFLAGS=' -m64 -I${MKLROOT}/include'
```

But it does not work with static MKL.

The above settings only work with gcc compiler.

---

Dynamic MKL with icc compiler also works with the following setting.

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ ../configure --with-blas=' -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_ilp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -lpthread -lm -ldl' CFLAGS=' -DMKL_ILP64 -qopenmp -I${MKLROOT}/include' CXXFLAGS=' -DMKL_ILP64 -qopenmp -I${MKLROOT}/include' CC=icc CXX=icpc
```

Comment: @AgrimPathak which comipler are you using? gcc or icc?

Comment: Either is fine.  I believe gcc/g++ is my current default.

Comment: Those commands work.  Any reason why Static MKL does not work?

Comment: bug of Ipopt, you could ask developer to fix it.

Comment: it is actually working! just link with MKL line advisorhttps://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/tools/oneapi/onemkl-link-line-advisor.html

Answer (score 3):

Following up on @kangshiyin 's answer: I found that one needs the `-liomp5` library and use the `LP64` integer representation instead of `ILP64`. I also defined the Fortran compilers in `F77` and `FC`. The configure command looked like:

```
../configure --prefix=${YOUR_PREFIX} \
--with-blas=' -L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core \
-lmkl_intel_thread -liomp5 -lpthread -lm -ldl' \
CC=icc CXX=icpc FC=ifort F77=ifort \
CFLAGS=' -DMKL_LP64 -qopenmp -I${MKLROOT}/include' \
CXXFLAGS='-std=c++11 -DMKL_LP64 -qopenmp -I${MKLROOT}/include' \
OPT_CCFLAGS="-Ofast" OPT_CXXFLAGS="-Ofast" OPT_FCFLAGS="-Ofast"
```

This worked on an Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS installation, with the 2017.0.2 versions of the Intel compilers and the MKL. The Ipopt version was 3.12.7.

**Update**: I tried this also on MacOS "El Capitan" (OS X 10.11.6). Turns out that you have to add the following linker flags to your invocation of `configure`:

```
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath,$MKLROOT/../compiler/lib -Wl,-rpath,$MKLROOT/lib"
```

otherwise the `libiomp5.dylib` library will not be found. This is apparently due to the changed security setup in "El Capitan", according to some posts on the [Intel C++ compiler forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-c-compiler).

Answer (score 1):

Ipopt needs to link against an LP64 Blas and Lapack library, it uses 32 bit integer indices. The ILP64 version of MKL you tried to link against is built for 64 bit integer indices.