# Linking Ipopt with MKL, problem with MUMPS

Tags: intel-mkl, ipopt

I am trying to link MKL with IPOPT for improved performance. I have read through the following thread which helped with a lot of my problems.

[Linking Ipopt with Intel MKL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038444/linking-ipopt-with-intel-mkl)

However, when I go to configure Ipopt using the following command.

```
    $ ../configure --prefix=/usr/local/ --with-blas='-L${MKLROOT}/lib/intel64 -Wl,--no-as-needed -lmkl_rt -lpthread -lm -ldl' CFLAGS='-m64 -I${MKLROOT}/include' CXXFLAGS='-m64 -I${MKLROOT}/include'
```

I get this error which seems cause problems when trying to build the ipopt libraries.

```
    $ checking for COIN-OR package Mumps... not given: Variable 'MKLROOT'     not defined in '/home/romela/Ipopt-3.12.10/build/ThirdParty/Mumps/coinmumps-uninstalled.pc
```

However, if I just install the non-optimized libraries through ThirdParty using ./get as instructed in https://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node13.html#SECTION00043100000000000000 then I get the following

```
    $ checking for COIN-OR package Mumps... yes: 1.6.0
```

I source mklvar.sh in my .bashrc file and when I run the following

```
    $ echo $MKLROOT
```

I get

```
    $ /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.2.199/linux/mkl
```

This appears that I am sourcing the MKL directory correctly. If anyone has any insight into my problem it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a question about the MUltifrontal Massively Parallel sparse direct Solver (MUMPS), but you've tagged it with the Massachusetts General Hospital Utility Multi-Programming System (MUMPS) tag.  That's an easy mistake to make.

You might have better luck getting your question answered if you change how it's tagged.

Ideally, some friendly Stack Overflow user with a sufficiently high reputation would create a new tag for the MUMPS Problem Solver, and differentiate it from the MUMPS nosql database.

Answer (score 0):

Using double quotes instead of single quotes for the arguments in your configure call.
With single quotes, variables like `${MKLROOT}` are not expanded.